# How to remove accidental files from the Jekyll _site folder

Tags: jekyll, static-site

So I just recently got started with Jekyll and had no clue what I was doing. I somehow managed to  get two files into the `_site` directory and now they are there to stay. I can delete these files, but when I run

```
bundle exec jekyll build
```

to build the site, the files are back.
 My question is, how can I remove these 2 files from the `_site` directory?
Here is a tree of the `_site` directory. The files I want to remove are `sync.py` and `README.md`.

```
.
├── 2020
│   └── 04
│       └── 24
│           └── get-system-platform-python.html
├── 404.html
├── README.md
├── about
│   └── index.html
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── images
│       ├── bkg.png
│       ├── blacktocat.png
│       ├── bullet.png
│       └── stack.png
├── favicon.ico
├── feed.xml
├── index.html
├── jekyll
│   └── update
│       └── 2020
│           └── 04
│               └── 24
│                   └── welcome-to-jekyll.html
└── sync.py
```

The Jekyll stuff is in this Github repo: https://github.com/noahbroyles/site-genny
I'm not sure if that helps or not because I have the `_site` directory in `.gitignore`.

Is it even possible to remove these files?
Any help is welcome!

Comment: We can help you but to understand why those files are generated, we need to see your source code. Any repository url ?

Comment: I edited my question to include the link to the github repo where I keep the code for the site build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add **sync.py** and to **README.md** the exclude list in **_config.yml**.

```
exclude:
 - sync.py
 - README.md
```